# Show custom message at the time of deploying a C# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

at the time of deploying the C# windows project i want to catch the exception and show my message if the connection string is not in correct format.

Comment: By "at the time of deploying" do you mean at application startup?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode method to respond to unhandled exceptions.

> It is often not feasible to catch all
>   of the exceptions thrown by Windows
>   Forms. Using this method, you can
>   instruct your application whether it
>   should catch all unhandled exceptions
>   thrown by Windows Forms components and
>   continue operating, or whether it
>   should expose them to the user and
>   halt execution.

See the [MSDN doc for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'deploying the C# windows project'? Are you trying to create an installer for the project?

If your connection string for a database connection then you could include the statement block containing the Open method in a try..catch block. Then show a message in case an exception is encountered. Connect will throw an exception if the connection string is in the incorrect format.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;server=(local);Initial Catalog=test;"))
{
    try
    {
         connection.Open();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sqlException.Message, "Unable to connect");
    }
}
```